# GWT: JSNI Function Call to getElementById() Returns Null

Tags: gwt, jsni

I am trying to use JSNI to display a Google Map within an Application. I have defined the script in my index.html page.

Here is the uibinder definition (snipped down to the essentials):

```
<g:HTMLPanel ui:field="mapboxV3ContentPanel">
    <!-- div for display of the actual map -->
    <div id="map"><!-- --></div>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Here is the initializeMap() native function:

```
private native void initializeMap() /*-{

    var latLng = new $wnd.google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latLng,
        mapTypeId: $wnd.google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var mapDiv = $doc.getElementById('map');
    if (mapDiv==null) {
        alert("MapDiv is null!");
    }
    var map = new $wnd.google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);
}-*/;
```

Unfortunately, mapDiv is null. Any help out there?

I am aware of the gwt-maps and gwt-maps-v3 projects. The first only supports v2 of the API, and gwt-maps-v3 will not work for me, hence the JSNI approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, your code should work, and I've quickly tested it (by the way, it shouldn't be related to the Google Maps API at all).

The only important thing is, that you add your `<div id="map">` **to the document** before you call `initializeMap()`.

Please try the following:

```java
@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {

  RootPanel.get().add(new MyUiBinderWidget()); // your widget with the map div
  initializeMap();
}
```

Note especially, that you can't call `initializeMap()` from inside the constructor of `MyUiBinderWidget`, because at that point, the widget isn't attached to the document yet.

Comment: @Jason: Putting `initializeMap()` directly after `initWidget(...)` is too early, and cannot work. (Please see the last paragraph I added to my answer.)

Comment: Okay, I read too quickly and deleted my other comments. If I can't do it in the constructor, where is the best place to do it?

Comment: @Jason: In my opinion, the best place is directly after the call to the constructor has finished, and the widget has been added to the document - just like in the example above.

Comment: Okay, overloading Widget.onLoad() seems to at least populate the div and not throw the exception anymore. Thanks, Chris.

Comment: @Jason: Putting the call into `onLoad()` is nice on the one hand, but on the other, it may introduce a tricky bug: If you ever reattach (i.e. move) your UiBinder widget to another parent (which is perfectly allowed), then `onLoad()` will be called again - I think, that's probably not what you want.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. In this particular case, I can live with it since the HTMLPanel showing the map is unlikely to be moved.